# Subtract months from a given date

Tags: matlab, date, bsxfun, date-math

I need to subtract months from a given DateCol in a matrix.  I was using the command `bsxfun(@minus, datevec(date),[0,3,0,0,0,0])`  to subtract 3 months from the given date.  You can see there is a bug in this code.  If the date is 1-Feb-2011, this code takes you to 1-Jan-2011 instead and NOT 1-Nov-2010.

mat = [100 734505 ; 200 734536 ; 200 734539] ;  % Col1 is ID and Col2 is Date

Can you suggest a vectorized approach?  For a single-date (outside of matrix), `addtodate(d, -3, 'month')` works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
newDateVector = arrayfun(@(x) addtodate(x, -3, 'month'), oldDateVector)
```